# Google Apps Backup Mail Accounts

Tags: email, backup, gmail, google-workspace

We are currently using Google Apps for Business with 10 users, however yesterday a member managed to delete all their emails.

Is there any free option in order to backup all emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Google Apps Admin Command line tool that allows extended admin provisions: [Google Apps Manager](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/)

This tool can be used to download email held within accounts into MBOX format

I recommend Google Vault however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [Google Apps Mail Backup](http://www.mailbakup.com/google-apps-backup) toolkit which is user friendly and all in one. Download and try demo, it supports all Windows and supports multiple mail account. It works well and save mailbox data in PST, MSG, MBOX and EML.

Comment: A new, unregistered user who visited the site, happened to stumble across an old question, and just happened to know the perfect software to recommend for it.  What are the odds?

Answer (score -2):

If they did this within the past 25 days you can try the [native G Suite restore option](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6052340?hl=en).

You specified free, but FYI some great paid options are [Spanning](https://spanning.com/), [Backupify](https://www.backupify.com/), and [SysCloud](https://www.syscloud.com/)

Comment: This is a 5 year old question, so in the past 25 days is very unlikely ...

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.